# How do I crop image in a fixed height slider for mobile view only in CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile, fixed

I am working on a new site where i have a fixed min-height slider 500px due "visible above the fold content" but i was struggling the whole day because on mobile view i want to get it centered and cropped. I would like to know what i have to modify in css that stay centered like now but not going to shrink from both sides instead its going to be cropped from both sides dynamically dependent from the ratio. I am looking for the answer like the whole day but haven't found a good solution anywhere.

My project: http://guede.com/horvath/index.html

[Mobile Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Finog.png)

Similar to this site:
https://www.invisionapp.com/blog

I hope somebody can help with it. Thanks...

CSS

```
   .moto-widget-slider li{
text-align:center;
width:100%;}

   .moto-widget-slider li img{
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
min-height:500px;}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="moto-widget-slider-list" data-moto-slider-options='{&quot;slideshowEnabled&quot;:true,&quot;slideshowDelay&quot;:5,&quot;slideshowAnimationType&quot;:&quot;fade&quot;,&quot;showNextPrev&quot;:true,&quot;showPaginationDots&quot;:true,&quot;showSlideCaptions&quot;:true,&quot;itemsCount&quot;:3}'>
                            <li><img src="mt-content/uploads/2017/10/slider3-min.png" alt="slider3-min.png"/>
                                    </li>
                            <li><img src="mt-content/uploads/2017/10/slider1-min.png" alt="slider1-min.png"/>
                                    </li>
                            <li><img src="mt-content/uploads/2017/10/slider2-min.png" alt="slider2-min.png"/>
                                    </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please provide code of what you have currently.

Comment: Updated it. Where is are the images inserted and also the slider + image code. I am modifying one of my purchased template but  admin surface pretty limited so i have to boost a little bit in the background.